# Error: No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to format date in a specific order

```
Time = DateTime.Parse(p.Time.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Data type of `Time` is `DateTime`

But i am getting this error:

> No overload for method "ToString" takes 1 arguments.

p is the object of the table from which i am getting Time.

```
  List<ProductImageMapWrapper> lstpm = new List<ProductImageMapWrapper>();
  lstpm = _db.ProductImageMaps.Where(i => i.ClientId == null && i.BrandId == null).Select(p => new ProductImageMapWrapper
  {
  Time= // Problem here
  }
```

Now, I tried using it this way

```
Time = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", p.Time))
```

but then i got this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.DateTime Parse(System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If the data type of `p.Time` is `DateTime` why are you parsing it ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: `Time` in `p` object is `string` or some other variable type

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but you can try using string.Format("dd-MM etc etc")

Comment: Even if i don't parse, i still get the same error

Comment: What are variables types for `Time` in which you assign and the `p.Time` which you are trying to parse......

Comment: The error is because they are trying to parse the formatted date string instead of parsing the date and using tostring to format the date after it is parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the Time property of both types (ProductImageMap and ProductImageMapWrapper) is a DateTime.  If that is true, then you should use `Time = p.Time`

There's a common misconception that a DateTime value somehow has a format.  Actually, you apply a given format when you convert the DateTime value into a string.  To copy a DateTime value from one place to another, just assign it.

Comment: Read sameer's answer below for more clearity with an example.

Answer (score 3):

```
String Time = Convert.ToDateTime(p.Time).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

parenthesis are in the wrong place.  You cannot parse it as that format.  You have to parse P, then format as the string.

```
DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to parse date from string and you can correct this for your structure to work:

```
string  p = "21-11-2013 11:12:13";              
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(p, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `p.Time` as `string` value in the date format you suggested, I think you want to parse `string` to `DateTime` as,

```
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        string format = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; //This should be format that you get in string
        List<ProductImageMapWrapper> lstpm = new List<ProductImageMapWrapper>();
        lstpm = _db.ProductImageMaps.Where(i => i.ClientId == null && i.BrandId == null).Select(p => new ProductImageMapWrapper
        {
            Time = DateTime.ParseExact(p.Time, format, provider)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Might Help**

```
 var selectQuery=from add in db.address
                select add.myDate.toString("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}");

 selectQuery.Distinct();
```

**Normal Convers.**

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              // Use current time
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";    // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

1.MMM     display three-letter month
2.ddd     display three-letter day of the WEEK
3.d       display day of the MONTH
4.HH      display two-digit hours on 24-hour scale
5.mm      display two-digit minutes
6.yyyy    displayfour-digit year

Answer (score 0):

You want to use DateTime.ToString(format) not Nullable.ToString(no 
  overload):

> DateTime? myDate = form.dteStartDate;
>   string sqlFormattedDate = myDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
>   Of course this doesn't handle the case that there is no value. Perhaps something like this:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDate.HasValue 
? myDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
: "<not available>";
```